# How to overload function in external node.js application?

Tags: node.js, overloading

I am new in node.js programming. I need to change behaviour of one function in existing node.js application (Haraka SMTP server).

What is the best practise for doing this? Should I use plugin or is there some another way how to overload one particular JS function in node.js app? Is this even possible?

Comment: Javascript does not allow function overloading. Functions are determined by name and holding object only. But there are several ways to decorate existing functions with additional functionality. But before: What do you mean by "use plugin"? If your library allows plugins this sounds like the best way to achieve your goal.

Comment: I need a solution especially for node.js application. I need to change all one existing function. By plugins I mean create own node.js plugin for Haraka SMTP server (I don't know, only a suggestion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node's `require` caches loaded objects. Therefore you can override an object's function, do something, call the original function, and do something afterwards.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var origRenameSync = fs.renameSync;
fs.renameSync = function(oldPath, newPath) {
    newPath += ".renamed";
    origRenameSync.call(this, oldPath, newPath);
    // do more here
};
```

This is a poor example, you should **never change core libraries this way**. You cannot foresee all side effects.

However, if you know what you do you can adopt existing libraries without changing them internally. It is a very flexible way to decorate functions.

Comment: Thanks! You write "you should never change fundamental Node modules this way" - so do you recommend this technique or don't? Is there some another way how to achieve this?

Comment: This is the only way I know to do it without touching the original library, if the module does not provide proper callbacks for your situation. In this case I recommend to try it this way, yes. Be aware of the fact that other modules that use the library get the changed version, too.

Comment: I see, thanks. What technique do you recommend in my situation? I really need to change only one line of code (the definition where to send bounce e-mail message), everything else is ok in this function and in all application.

Comment: I don't know the framework nor your situation exactely, but if you cannot change the behavior using options or callbacks I would choose this way, yes.